# How to remove duplicate custom object from List?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I have a `List<MyDTO>`.  It has properties like `projName,projID,projReleaseDate,comments` etc. I want to create a new list object `List<Timestamp>` where i have to store all the projReleaseDates without duplicates.

I started trying the code as below, but could not proceed..

```
List<Timestamp> datesList = new ArrayList<Timestamp>();
List<MyDTO> myDTOList = getInformation();

for(MyDTO dtoList : myDTOList){

//dtoList.getProjReleaseDate(); //return the release date

}
```

How can i store the projReleaseDates in the new List object(`datesList`) without duplicates.How can i know that the current object value and previous object value is same?

Comment: To answer your last question: You could check that by using `List#contains`. But note that this method is very slow, for `ArrayList` it will move from left to right through all elements until the result is clear. This data-structure was just not made for *contains*-queries. It provides fast random access (per index).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to omit duplicates also maintain insertion order, you can use `LinkedHashSet`, make sure you have properly overridden `equals` and `hashCode` methods

```
        Set<Timestamp> results = myDTOList
                .stream()
                .map(MyDTO::getProjReleaseDate)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(LinkedHashSet::new, Set::add, Set::addAll);
```

using `List` stream with `distinct()` [less efficient than `Set`]

```
        List<Timestamp> result = myDTOList
                .stream()
                .map(MyDTO::getProjReleaseDate)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can i check for nulls and omit adding the null value to the Set when i use java8 to achieve this, as for few project there are null values..

Answer (score 1):

No. Don't take a `List`. Take a `Set` so that it eliminate dupes.

```
Set<Timestamp> datesList = new HashSet<Timestamp>();
List<MyDTO> myDTOList = getInformation();

for(MyDTO dtoList : myDTOList){

  datesList.add(dtoList.getProjReleaseDate()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Set` instead, it can done in one-line in  Java 8 using stream,

```
Set<Timestamp> results = myDTOList
                         .stream()
                         .map(MyDTO::getProjReleaseDate)
                         .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: thanks for all the inputs..Just realized that i cannot be done on java side,i have to do that same in js side https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48605273/create-a-new-object-by-avoiding-the-duplicate-and-null-values . Any inputs?

Comment: @user8115347 then your question isn't valid and none of the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

The `List` class, as you have noticed, allows duplicates. The `Set` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)) class however does not, it is well suited for your desire.

Note that you lose order in a set. If you need to maintain an order you can use [SortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)s like `TreeSet` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)) (for specific order) or `LinkedHashSet` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)) (for insertion order).

Your code with could then look like this:

```
// Create set
Set<Timestamp> dates = new HashSet<>();
List<MyDTO> myDTOList = getInformation();

for (MyDTO dtoList : myDTOList) {
    Timestamp ts = dtoList.getProjReleaseDate();
    // Add to set
    dates.add(ts);
}
```

Or, by using the streaming API (since Java 8):

```
Set<Timestamp> dates = getInformation().stream()  // Stream<MyDTO>
    .map(MyDTO::getProjReleaseDate)               // Stream<Timestamp>
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());                 // Set<Timestamp>
```